# Composition with a projection remain surjective in a neighborhood of the parameter

Tags: real-analysis, operator-theory, hilbert-spaces

Let $H$ be an Hilbert space and $\varphi:H\to \mathbb R^m$ a smooth map.

It is known that the map $u\mapsto d_u\varphi$ is continuous from $H$ to the space of linear operators $L(H,\mathbb R^m)$.

Let $u_0$ be such that $\textrm{Im}d_{u_0}\varphi=\mathrm{span}\{e_1,\dotso, e_{m-1}\}\subsetneq \mathbb R^m$.

I consider $P:\mathbb R^m\to\mathrm{span}\{e_1,\dotso,e_{m-1}\}$ to be the orthogonal projection.

Also, let $x_i\in H$ be such that $d_{u_0}\varphi x_i=e_i$.

**First Question**: is it true that the composition map $P\circ d_u\varphi:H\to\mathrm{span}\{e_1,\dotso, e_{m-1}\}$ is surjective if $u$ belongs to a small neighborhood of $u_0$?

My answer is yes because this is obviously true by construction for $u_0$ and since the map $u\mapsto P\circ d_u\varphi$ is a composition of continuous maps then the conclusion should follows. If this is true then I have a

**Second Question** Is it possible to find $x_i(u),i=1,\dotso,m-1$, defined in a (possibly smaller) neighborhood $V$ of $u_0$ such that 
$$P\circ d_u\varphi x_i(u)=e_i,\; x_i(u_0)=x_i\quad\forall i=1,\dotso,m-1?$$
My opinion is that if the answer to the first question is positive, then this should follow from the implicit function theorem.

Am I right or am I missing something? If I am wrong can you please provide me with a counterexample?

Many thanks,

Guido

Comment: Consider the finite-dimensional subspace $L = \operatorname{span} \{x_1, \dotsc, x_{m-1}\}$ of $H$. Then you can apply the theorems from ordinary multivariable calculus to $P\circ \varphi \circ \iota$, where $\iota \colon L\hookrightarrow H$ is the inclusion.

Comment: so my reasoning is right?

Comment: Yes, the reasoning is right. Of course the details need to be filled in.